# Generate random points - limit number per tile of total area

Tags: matlab, random

I am trying to create a set of random points, but limit the number in each say, 1/4th, of the total area. So imagining my x & y ranged from 0 to 2, and 0 to 2, I would only get a certain number of randomly generated points within the tile (0

So far, I thought I could just create an if statement for each tile, then if the randomly generated point falls within the tile, it gets added to a count, which then if the count exceeds or is not great enough for that tile, another point will be generated and checked. This count method doesn't seem to work, instead of each of the counts going up, I get only the count for tile 4 to increase.

```
n = 8;
used = [];
k = 0;
a1_count = 0;
a2_count = 0;
a3_count = 0;
a4_count = 0;
while k<n
    x = rand*2;
    y = rand*2;


    if 0 < x < 1 && 0 < y < 1
        a1_count = a1_count + 1;
    end
    if 1 < x < 2 && 0 < y < 1
        a2_count = a2_count + 1;
    end
    if 0 < x < 1 && 1 < y < 2
        a3_count = a3_count + 1;
    end
    if 1 < x < 2 && 1 < y < 2
        a4_count = a4_count + 1;
    end

    used(end+1,:) = [x;y];
    k = k+1;
end
```

If the counts worked correctly, I would then have a min & max, and then use an if statement to check if a count is outwith the min & max, and if so use the continue statement to go on or not.

Can anyone tell me why the count is not increasing for each area? If I run this code, I get a1_count, a2_count, a3_count = 0, while a4_count = 8, even though the points lie within the a1, a2 and a3 boundaries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An expression of the form `0 < x < 1` needs to be written as `0 < x && x < 1`.

`0 < x < 1` is syntactically valid so therefore does not flag up any warning or error: it is the same as `(0 < x) < 1`. Note that `(0 < x)` is itself either 0 or 1.

This explains why `1 < x < 2 && 1 < y < 2` always evaluates to 1 and therefore `a4_count` is *always* increased: `1 < x < 2` is `(1 < x) < 2` which is always `1`, irrespective of the value of `x`. Similarly for `1 < y < 2`.